# Animate parent on child removal

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have this cart that contains `.cartItem` children, with their CSS below :

```
.cartItemsContainer {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.cartItem {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.cartItemSlide {
    padding-left: 350px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I have this Javascript code that is executed when I delete a cart item :

```
// make it disappear with a CSS transition, then delete it when out of sight
cartItem.classList.add('cartItemSlide');
onTransitionEnd(cartItem, 'padding-left', () => 
{
    cartItem.parentNode.removeChild(cartItem);
});
```

So I have my cart item that slides to the right, and is then deleted when this transition is over. The **problem** is that when the cart item is removed from the DOM, there is **no height transition for my cartItemsContainer**

I want the parent height to be smoothly reduced when its child is removed, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't animate `height` when height value is `auto`, you have to set two explicit heights. That's the CSS "issue", look through the [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick possible solution, you can adjust it to your need:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  p[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    myFunc(e);
  });
}

function myFunc(e) {
  e.target.innerHTML = '';
  e.target.style.maxHeight = '0px';
  e.target.style.padding = '0';
}
```

```css
div {
  outline : 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id=div class=div>
  <p class=p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laboriosam itaque dolore aspernatur labore, blanditiis nesciunt sapiente architecto veniam quo culpa, quibusdam beatae dolorem esse dignissimos commodi, distinctio laborum perferendis.</p>
  <p class=p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur id exercitationem magni esse non, perferendis, nemo doloremque impedit eos nobis in distinctio sunt tempora laudantium? Veniam aliquid ex nemo quod!</p>
</div>
```

Try to click on `p` element to see the animation.

Comment: You can note that I am forced to use `max-height` value set in px as `auto` and `100%` values can not be animated.